# Unable to mount one of your folders. Please check your folders in Homestead.yaml

Tags: laravel, vagrant, directory, shared, homestead

I'm reinstalling my Homestead/Laravel using Vagrant on my new machine.. but I can't get past this error:

> Unable to mount one of your folders. Please check your folders in Homestead.yaml

This is my configuration:

- Vagrant Version: 2.0.3
- Homestead pulled from [here](https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git) using Git Desktop and placed on my user folder.
- Homestead.yaml is unaltered
- Windows 10 with all updates
- Virtualbox version is 5.2.8 r121009 (Qt5.6.2)

to reproduce the error I use `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision` (if already up)

Everything seems to work normally but the shared folder does not show up.

Comment: Can you include the content of the yaml file where you are configuring the mounts please?

Comment: homestead.yaml is unaltered. Solved the problem by creating the code folder before mounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by creating the Code directory. It needs to exist before trying to connect it.

After using homestead destroy and homestead up it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you have to make sure that the directory paths are not in this format `~/code/` but change them to `c:\path\to\your\code\` for all occurences of such paths

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Ubuntu(18.04 that's what i have)
make sure that the folders map: exist, you can create them first for example the /code folder must be created first then re-run vagrant reload --provision
that's how i managed to resolve that issue